# Rewrites in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I need to enter a bunch or rewrites in my conf file in Nginx. I am not very experienced so I copied what I found before, example.

```
location = /index.php/blog/blog/xxx/yyy/ {
  return 301 /index.php/blog/xxx/yyy/;
 }
```

However I was told that the best way is the following:

```
location ^~ /index.php/blog/blog/xxx/yyy/ {
  rewrite ^/index.php/blog/xxx/yyy/;
 }
```

Which one id the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is more correct, both `location` as well as the `return` -wise, and it'll work faster.

FWIIW, your second snippet looks like it's missing a space in the `rewrite` after `^`, and it's also less efficient, both `location` as well as `rewrite`-wise.

References:

- http://nginx.org/r/location
- http://nginx.org/r/return
- http://nginx.org/r/rewrite